# Localization run time not changing

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, localizable.strings

I have followed the step in many tutorial for localization.

I added the storyboard localization , Added string files . And chnaged the vlue in both string file as well as in storyboard.

For example, if i am trying `English , french`

Then in storyboard we have :-> `Main.Stroyboard`

**Main.Strings(French)**

```
/* Class = "UILabel"; text = "Hamza Smith"; ObjectID = "2gA-Wx-5v2"; */
"2gA-Wx-5v2.text" = "Hamza Smith";
```

Same in `language.String`

**Language.string(French)**

```
"Hamza Smith" = "some thing";
```

Then in code on change language button action :

```
 Bundle.setLanguage(lang: "Fn"). //FN for example i am adding
```

My code :

```
extension Bundle {
    private static var bundle: Bundle!

    public static func localizedBundle() -> Bundle! {
        if bundle == nil {
            var appLang = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "app_lang") ?? "en"
            if Bundle.main.path(forResource: appLang, ofType: "lproj") == nil {
                appLang = "en"
            }
            let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: appLang, ofType: "lproj")
            bundle = Bundle(path: path!)
        }

        return bundle;
    }

    public static func setLanguage(lang: String) {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(lang, forKey: "app_lang")
        let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: lang, ofType: "lproj")
        bundle = Bundle(path: path!)
    }
}
extension String {
    func localized() -> String {
        return NSLocalizedString(self, tableName: nil, bundle: Bundle.localizedBundle(), value: "", comment: "")
    }

    func localizeWithFormat(arguments: CVarArg...) -> String{
        return String(format: self.localized(), arguments: arguments)
    }
}
```

And my iboutlet label has:

```
 titleLabel.text = "Hamza Smith".localized()
```

Now on tap on my save button after select any language its not changing. I killed the app and relaunch again. But its not changing.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using a custom name for the `.strings` file, you need to provide it as `tableName` in the `NSLocalizedString` method.

```
extension String {
    func localized() -> String {
        return NSLocalizedString(self, tableName: "Language", bundle: Bundle.localizedBundle(), value: "", comment: "") // <- note the new parameter tableName
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

First I want to ask do you have key in your localized strings as "Hamza Smith"?

`NSLocalizedString` takes key as first argument that exists in your localized strings, for example you can create something like this:

```
extension String {
    
    public func localize(key: String) -> String {
        return NSLocalizedString(key, tableName: nil, bundle: Bundle.localizedBundle(), value: "", comment: "")
    }
  
}
```

and than call it like this:

```
label.text = .localize(key: "<localized string key>")
```

or if you want to use like your implementation you need to call it like this:

```
label.text = "<localized string key>".localized()
```

Edit:
If you want to change to french, you need to set "fr" not "Fn" :)